# Tricky spring on a surface question

Tags: forces, momentum, harmonic-oscillator, spring

I have this relative simple-looking question that I haven't been able to solve for hours now, it's one of those questions that just drive you nuts if you don't know how to do it.
This is the scenario:

I have a [spring](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_P4EHIyposmM/TImv2-brnOI/AAAAAAAAAMw/nK-NO8JUSEU/s1600/1781_PotApp_FlexibleMetal_Spring_Big.jpg) that is on a flat surface, the springs details are like this:

spring constant = 100N/m

height = 0.1m

mass = 0.5kg

g = 10m/s^2

there is nothing attached to the spring.
The initial force exerted on the surface is 5N.
I compress the spring halfway until the force exerted on the surface is double, now 10N and then let it go.

The (simple) oscillation starts, and at one point the force exerted on the surface will be 0N (weightless).

I need to find out how much time has passed after letting it go, and reaching weightlessness.

as in:
10(N)---time--->0(N)

p.s. not homework, read comments.

Comment: Looks like a straight homework question, so I've tagged it as such. Please feel free to help, but don't answer the question fully/directly.

Comment: You say there is no mass attached to the spring. If that is so then the mass is distributed along the length of the spring. So rather than a simple differential equation, you have a partial differential equation for the position and velocity at all points along the spring as a function of time. You want to solve for the lowest  eigenvalue mode. Assume time dependence is exp(i*omega*t), solve for the x dependence of displacement and velocity. Only certain discrete frequencies, (eigenvalues) will satisfy the boundary conditions.

Comment: @Noldorin It is no homework question. and I would like you to restore it as such. if you want proof, I don't mind it being answered later, but I'd prefer to know it sooner as I can't stop thinking about it. I don't mind if it's just help, but I don't like inappropriate tagging.

Comment: @Noldorin I prefer answers that explain things, my solution is 0.1secs but I want to fully understand it. @Omega Centauri I have no clue what a eigenvalue is?

Comment: The force on the bottom of the spring until it takes off is 0=(Normal force)-mg+kx, when it lifts you have (Normal force)=0, that gives you x, you get acc for center of mass by F=ma, solve for t by standard motion formula t=f(x,a).

Comment: how do you do the "standard motion formula"?

Comment: I mean by the definition of a=x'' and initial conditions.

Comment: with basic physics, the "t" value self destructs, and I never get it... My answer was with F=k/2(change of height)^2 = mass/2(vel)^2 but I suspect it might be way off.

Comment: @kakemonsteret is a=x'': a = differential of x? and what is m? it can't be mass as the whole spring does not move, only part of it's mass actually shifts. please elaborate what you mean by t=f(x,a)? x = 0.05 but where to go from there?

Comment: Voting to close as simple pendulum problem. This is waaay too elementary for this site in my opinion. @Yuri: assuming simple elastic setting, force is just $F = k x$ where $x$ is the distance from equilibrium. Solution is then $x(t) = A \cos(\omega t + \alpha)$ where $\omega$ depends on the $k$ (the stiffness of the string) and mass of the spring and $\alpha$ and $A$ depend on the initial conditions (i.e. how much do you compress the spring and what is the initial velocity).

Comment: @marek Are you sure?  I actually don't know how to do the problem; after working on it for 15 minutes I have some equations of motion that I don't know how to solve.

Comment: To be more specific, I modeled it as $n$ point masses of mass $m/n$, separated by $n-1$ springs of spring constant $k(n-1)$ and rest length $l/(n-1)$.  Using the boundary condition that the bottom point mass is motionless, I have an $(n+1)\times(n+1)$ matrix to diagonalize.  I'm not sure what coordinate transformation will do that.

Comment: Angular Frequency = squareroot(Spring constant / Spring Mass ) (angular frequency was a big key here)

Comment: x(t) is distance along the axis at any point in time, but what units is x counted in? meters? but I don't know the distance along the axis between the 2 points because I don't know the points in time! and is the Cos in radians or degrees?

Comment: ok, what exactly is "x" in terms of this spring? because my calculator is showing errors with the inverse of cosine.

Comment: I know the angular frequency = sqrt(spring constant / mass)
so it must be sqrt(200) rad/sec
the angle between the 2 maximums is exactly 1Pi, so it must mean Pi/sqrt(200) = the time that I want, is approx 0.222sec? or am I completely wrong?

Comment: @Marek your method of solving it seems to be completely different from Omegas method.

Comment: @YuriKolovsky: sure, because I used a simplified model. If you want to solve fully realistic spring then there's no way we could help you as that object is too hard to model analytically. So you have to make precise what kind of approximation you want to use.

Comment: @Mark, I am sure if the question asks just about simple harmonic oscillator. If that is not the case then I also don't see any simple way to solve the problem (unless I assume some other simplifying conditions).

Comment: @Mark so you suggest that either A. the question is too easy and needs to be closed, or B. it is too hard and won't be solved? I don't know of any potential simplifying conditions except making it a simple harmonic, and if that makes it at least potentially solvable, then I'm all for it.

Comment: @Yuri Are you sure that comment was directed at me, or was it at Marek?  I don't think the question is too hard to be solved.  It is too hard for me personally to get the solution without some concerted effort.

Comment: @mark, sorry it was at Marek.

Comment: @Yuri: I am saying that the question is not well-defined because hardness of the problem differs brutally between various approximation schemes. That's why you have to make explicit what are you after. What @Omega said in the beginning was correct, you might model the spring as a elastic system with infinite degrees of freedom and use Fourier analysis to solve it. But it was not at all clear to me that this is what the question asks about. Please, let us know.

Comment: @YuriKolovsky: You must understand that it seems very much like homework! I shall undo the tag, but please make it clear in future situations.

Comment: @Noldorin I am sorry, will do in the future, It was my first question and I was unaware of this.
@Marek I made the hypothetical problem myself, it was a follow up of a spring related question I got from a younger friend that got me thinking, I was not aware that there will be such a massive difference of difficulty, but I'd like to know the solutions to both the simplified model and the brutal one if possible, just to see how much the answer will vary, and thanks for helping me with this bugger.

Comment: @UriKolovsky: No worries, that's understandable. Hope you get a good answer to this question anyway. :)

Answer (score 1):

I assume for simplicity that the spring constant  has a quite a high value so that the settling down of the spring under its own weight is insignificant.

Designations:

$x$-vertical displacement of the center of mass of the spring from its equilibrium position.
$l$-vertical displacement of the top of the spring from its equilibrium position.
$m$-the mass of the spring.
$k$-the spring constant.
$g$-gravitational acceleration.

First of all let's highlight the following relation: $$x=\frac{2}{3}l$$ Its derivation is elementary but too long to present here.

The next step is write down the equation of the conservation of energy:
$$m\frac{\dot{x}^2}{2}+\frac{3}{2}kx^2+mg(x_0-x)= \frac{3}{2}kx_0^2=const$$ $x_0=x(0)$ is an initial displacement of mass center of the spring from its equilibrium position. After differentiating with respect to $t$ we get the equation of the motion of the center of mass of the spring:

$$\ddot{x}+\frac{3k}{m}x-g=0$$ According to initial conditions $x(0)=x_0= \frac{2}{3}l_0$ and $\dot{x}(0)=0$ the solution of this equation:
$$x(t)=\frac{g}{\omega_0^2}+\left(x_0-\frac{g}{\omega_0^2}\right)cos(\omega_0t);\omega_0^2=\frac{3k}{m}$$ At the moment of the departure from the ground the following holds:

$$-mg=kl=\frac{3}{2}kx$$or $$x=-\frac{2g}{\omega_0^2}$$ Minus sign indicates that a vertical coordinate is above the equilibrium. Thus, the time we are looking for is:

$$t=\frac{1}{\omega_0}arccos\left(-\frac{3g}{-g+x_0\omega_0^2}\right)= \frac{1}{\omega_0}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}+arcsin\frac{3g}{x_0\omega_0^2-g}\right)$$ The formula has a meaning if
$$x_0>\frac{4g}{\omega_0^2}$$ I would point out the assumption at the top of the post! For the given data this is probably not a good assumption. But as a first approximation maybe it fits.

Comment: I'm still gradually decomposing each step.

Comment: so the period of oscillation at the start where at length deviation of 0.05m, x1 = 0.05*2/3, so angular velocity at the start is: w1 = sqrt(2g/x1) = sqrt(600), so the period of the wave at the start is T=2Pi/w1, T=2Pi/sqrt(600), and I need 1/2T, so the answer is t = Pi/sqrt(600), which is 0.128s I'm probably missing the added acceleration over this period of time... but otherwise I'm just plain stuck...

Comment: @Yuri: There were some errors in the solution. It should be correct now. What exactly do you not understand?

Comment: w0 is the natural frequency, right? I found that w0 = (1/2Pi)*sqrt(mass/k), so where did you get the ω0^2=3k/m from?

Comment: @Yuri: $\omega_0^2=\frac{3k}{m}$ is angular frequency($\frac{rad}{s}$). It follows from the equation of the motion of the spring. You are talking about  temporal frequency(herz).

Comment: identical symbols for different things sure can get confusing... then in that case my problem is that I don't see how you get the angular frequency from the equation of motion of the spring. (p.s. how do you do the math symbols in the comment?)

Comment: @Yuri: The equation of motion:  $\ddot{x}+\frac{3k}{m}x-g=0$ or  $\ddot{x}+\omega_0^2x-g=0$

Comment: @Yuri: You can do the math in a comment in the same way as you do when you write a post.

Comment: (cant figure out how to do comment math, refuses to work) but how do you know that ω0^2 = 3k/m in the first place? or is it just a known formula? because I've seen it only as ω0^2 = k/m http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_frequency so where did you get the "3" multiplier from?

Comment: @Yuri: This would be $\omega_0^2=\frac{k}{m}$ if we had a zero-mass spring with a bob on its top that has a mass $m$. But in given case the mass $m$ is distributed uniformly along the spring. Note that in this last case the frequency is a little bit higher which is reasonable.

Comment: @Yuri: Note that  $F=kl=\frac{3}{2}kx$. That means if we write out the equation of motion for the center of mass of the spring then the spring constant is now $\frac{3}{2}k$ not simply $k$.

Comment: ok, makes sense. now the formula holds true only if x0 > 4g/(3k/m), g=10, k=100, m=0.5, so x0 has to be > 0.06m but if I use x=2/3L it means that with an (start length reduction) L0 of 0.05, x is smaller than the required amount for the equation to be true, and there is no solution to the question?

Comment: @Yuri: That means that the spring will not jump off the surface.

Comment: @Martin so if all I'm getting are errors because in the scenario it never jumps off the table, then how do I get the time? :S

Comment: so, if I take the x0 where it does ever so slightly jumps up, where k=100,m=0.5,g=10, then I get a value around t = Pi/sqrt(600) = 0.12825s which happens to be the same answer I got before.

Comment: @Yuri: Does this time seem reasonable or not?

Comment: @Martin It does seem reasonable, but I don't know if it is :)

Answer (score 0):

Basically at a point on the spring where y is displacement from the equilibrium condition, you'll get a differential equation $d^2/dt^2 (Y \times density) = -d^2Y/dZ^2 \times k$ the spring constant. (sorry I can't use Latex)! If we postulate that solutions look like $e^{ikZ +i\omega t}$, $ 2\pi\omega$ will be the frequency. Plug in $\omega$ or $k$ and you can solve for the other one.

Then at $Z$=height of zero the boundary condition is displacement =0, this will imply that the spatial part of the solution looks like $\sin{(kx)}$. At the top of the spring $dY/dZ$ must be zero, else there would be an unbalanced force, that means that $kZ$ must be an odd multiple of $\pi/2$. The $\omega$ values that satisfy these conditions are your eigenvalues.

Next you need to discover the amplitudes for the infinately number of modes excited. i.E.
your initial displacement as a function of Z is proportional to Z, and you must find Ai such that
  $$Z=\sum_{i= odd N} Ai\cos{(ikZ)} (k*.1 = \pi/2)$$.
  You may need to lookup Fourier analysis to do this, but you should get a simple formula
for all the Ai. The solution at any future time will be the sum of these (note each term as its own frequency dependence). You should discover that when time is $\pi$ times the lowest eigenvalue, you've reversed the value of F everywhere, so that will be your answer.

Undergrad physics should teach solving the wave equation, and show you how to apply these methods.